# Logstash filter - name fields dynamically

Tags: logstash

I've got log lines in the following format and want to extract fields:

```
"field1" => "content1","field2" => "content2",field3" => "content3",...
```

I neither know the field names, nor the number of fields.

I tried it with ruby  but got errors:

> Error: Expected one of #, {, } at line 8, column 51 (byte 113) after filter {
>       ruby {
>           code => "
>               fieldArray = event['message'].split('"

my conf are as follows,

```
input {
    stdin {}
      }

filter {
ruby {
    code => "
        fieldArray = event['message'].split('", "')
        for field in fieldArray
            field = field.delete '",'
            field = field.delete '"'
            result = field.split(': ')
            event[result[0]] = result[1]
        end
    "
  }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
      }
 }
```

please tell me how to fix these errors?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ruby problem is because you have double-quotes inside your code.  Since you're using double-quotes to surround the entire code block, you can't use them inside.  I would imagine that escaping them would work.

You might also look into the kv{} filter, which typically handles such fields with ease.  If not, convert the "=>" to ":" with mutate->gsub and try the json{} filter.